# E-mail Verification with Phonegap Cordova App

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have a phonegap cordova application wherein the registration process is the following:

1. Register
2. Email Verification
3. Redirect to web application when email link is clicked.

## Problem

When the user clicks the link to redirect, it needs to open the browser. How do I make it so it opens the application instead of opening the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over your Application's back-end, instead of sending a link to your user's email to verify, why not change the process itself and send out a verification code that your user can copy and paste back to the application and then verify it there.